# Web service instantiate object C#.NET

Tags: c#, web-services, constructor, instance

I am pretty new to web services, C#, and .NET.
I want to use a connection object in my web method in order to write data on database but I don't where to instantiate this object, it's quite ridiculous to instantiate it and then destroy it in the web method.
I want my connection instance to be accessible every time,so is there a kind of a constructor or something to make this properly.

Comment: It's not ridiculous to create an object, use it and then destroy it right away. Why do you think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know what you mean: You don't want to repeat the connection management code in every method. That would be ridiculous, indeed.

I do it like this: I use [this technique](http://blog.caraulean.com/2008/02/13/httpcontext-idiom-for-windows-communication-foundation/) to create a per-request connection. When the WCF call has ended I destroy the connection.

So during the call I can rely on this connection being present. It will be cleaned up correctly.

Unfortunately, WCF has no equivalent for HttpContext.Items builtin so we have to hack it in using an extension.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to instantiate the database connection class in your web-method. I would argue that there is nothing ridiculous about instantiating such an object in your web-method:

- C# is an `object-orientated` language. Your not going to achieve much without creating objects; and
- Most ADO.NET connection objects (including SQL Server & Oracle) implement connection pooling so you are not going to create a physical connection to the server every time you create a new connection object. Instead the database library will manage a pool of connections for you.

I'd recommend something like this to make sure you release the connection after the webservice call:

```
// This example uses SQL-Server connections, but most
// ADO.NET database drivers are similar.
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConnStr)) 
{
   UseConnection(conn);
} 
// connection released to pool here automatically.
```